# Populating a XSL template with XML variables working partially

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm using XSL to render an image ( on the server side ) and i want to do it as generic as possible.

for example i got this variable

`<xsl:variable name="shows" select="document('includes/shows.xml')"/>`

that references an XML file. this is the content of the XML

```
<show id='2'>
    <logo>url('images/background.png')</logo>
    <border>8pt solid #f9c514</border>
    <bordertop>6pt solid #f9c514</bordertop>
    <headercolor>#f9c514</headercolor>
    <backgroundimage>svg/bg.svg</backgroundimage>
  </show>
```

which contains a lot of different shows, each formatted as above. Using this, and providing the right ID, my variables will get populated with those values. When i use this :

```
<xsl:value-of select="$shows/all/show[@id=2]/logo"/>
```

it gets correctly evaluted and display the right image. Same for the border and border color. Therefore this doesn't work :

```
<fo:simple-page-master master-name="thepage" page-width="4cm" margin-top="0.6cm" page-height="8.4cm">
    <fo:region-body region-name="xsl-region-body"/>
    <fo:region-before extent="8.4cm" background-image="$shows/all/show[@id=2]/backgroundimage"/>      
</fo:simple-page-master>
```

It doesnt crash though, the image does not have any bg that's all. I checked the value and i correctly get `svg/bg.svg`, also when i put directly `background-image='svg/bg.svg'` it also works. Any idea why it doesnt work if it comes from an XML file

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [Attribute Value Templates](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#attribute-value-templates) here when you want an expression evaluated directly in an attribute

```
<fo:region-before extent="8.4cm" background-image="{$shows/all/show[@id=2]/backgroundimage}"/>
```